# Passar props via Bottom Tab Navigator

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com React Native e estou tendo um problema, alguém saberia me dizer como passar dados de uma tela para um Bottom Tab Navigator?
Tenho uma tela chamada MainPerson com um Bottom Tab navigator, como mostra o trecho de código abaixo:

```
const AppTabNavigatorPerson = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        'Perfil': {
            screen: Perfil,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarOptions: {
                    activeTintColor: "#00008B",
                    inactiveTintColor: "#000000",
                    activeBackgroundColor: "#6495ED",
                    inactiveBackgroundColor: "#A9A9A9",
                    style: {
                        height: 50,
                    },
                    labelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 15,
                    },
                },
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
                    <Icon name="user" color={tintColor} size={15} />
            }
        },
    }
);
```

Até aqui tudo bem, a página Perfil é exibida corretamente quando acesso o MainPerson, porém, queria saber se é possível passar algum dado para essa tela Perfil, ou seja, se existe alguma possibilidade de passar um valor para um Bottom Tab Navigator além de screen ou navigationOptions.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui achar a solução, mas para quem tiver o mesmo problema, aqui vai a resposta:

```
const AppTabNavigatorPerson = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Perfil: {
            screen: (props) => <Perfil {...props} />,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarOptions: {
                    activeTintColor: "#00008B",
                    inactiveTintColor: "#000000",
                    activeBackgroundColor: "#6495ED",
                    inactiveBackgroundColor: "#A9A9A9",
                    style: {
                        height: 50,
                    },
                    labelStyle: {
                        fontSize: 15,
                    },
                },
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
                    <Icon name="user" color={tintColor} size={15} />
            }
        },
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
            <Icon name="handshake" color={tintColor} size={15} />
    }
};
```

Basta passar o props diretamente no screen.